# How to do I extract values from a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas series object where each value is a list. How do i change this series to DataFrame with columns say `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`

Series I have -

```
0 [0.7142, 0.833334, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1 [0.7142, 0.273924, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

etc

expected dataframe-

```
id      a      b      c    d    e    f 
0    0.71428 0.833334 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0 
1    0.71428 0.273924 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: are `['a','b','c'...]` an example or will be be your actual columns ?

Comment: They are dummy column names, actual names would be like 'ctc_max', 'ctc_min' etc

Answer (score 4):

IIUC:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(s), columns = ['a','b', 'c','d','e','f'])
```